# Can't install HP 1515 printer

Tags: printing, hp, hplip

I'm not a technician and find most Ubuntu instructions are incomprehensible. I bought a printer for the first time in my life today, an HP 1515. I eliminated all Microsoft stuff from my computer last year. The HP installation disc seems incompatible with Ubuntu or with my Toshiba Satellite laptop. When I tried to understand the Ubuntu help page, I was invited to upgrade from Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10. This in turn requires me to install something. I attempted to install Adobe Flash Player, but I couldn't. This also asks me to install updates to Ubuntu 13.04. This was also impossible to understand or to do.

Is there a simple way to make my printer work? I'd like to stick with free software, but I don't like these complications. I still haven't figured out how to double space, how to put numbers on pages, etc., and may be forced back to Microsoft if Ubuntu doesn't become user friendly for mere writers, not technicians. Thanks to all who offer suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Ubuntu becomes easy when you learn it. It's just a new system and it's _very_ user-friendly. Windows just damaged your perception, so forget about it if you want to stay with open-source. And you should update to 13.10, because 13.04 is End-Of-Life, so it's not supported here.

Answer (score 1):

It's not too bad - throw the disks away!

Open a terminal and install the HP driver system for ubuntu:

`sudo apt-get install hplip`

After it gets down downloading the program for your computer, enter the command

`hp-setup`

Then follow the prompts on the screen

You can also install hplip from the Ubuntu software center

Answer (score 0):

**@Adobe Flash Player:** Adobe has dropped the development project for Ubuntu on this software; therefore, they will only release bugfixes and eventual security exploits on it's current archaic version (we have 11.2 and the actual windows/mac player is above the 13.xx version already). You maybe able to install but keep in mind it's an outdated, slow version.

About the printer and still on the Flash Player's topic, you can install both through a visual interface called Ubuntu Software Center. Search for it in the dash, then click or hit enter when an application that remembers an orange shop bag comes up

[image]

If you can't upgrade your system, maybe your packages might be conflicting and holding back further installations; you'll then have to fix those broken packages, it can be done through the Synaptic Pack Manager or through `sudo apt-get install -f` in a terminal. Try reading the output of those operations if it can't be fixed through those procedures, since you might have to uninstall them manually.

It's strange since my printer (also HP) got detected automatically by the system. Try installing the HP libs through the Software Center.

EDIT: Remember you'll have to be on an ADMIN user in order to install new applications!